# How can I translate several HTML files without using Google Translator's Kit

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, translation

I need to translate several PHP files (HTML Code + PHP Tags) into another language. 
Google Translator's Kit allows this, but clears the PHP Tags, erases class="" attributes (?!) and adds html, head tags & what not. Completely useless.

How can I (ideally in batch) translate these files using any kind of automated translation service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bmargulies is the most clear-cut way of doing it. However, it takes times.

If you're in a pinch, or want to cut corners, a relatively simple way to do it is to use regular expressions to filter your code out *yourself*. Match  over multiple lines (/s flag in preg), store the match, and replace with a hash. Any hash. Just make sure it doesn't map to anything in any language.
Do the same for HTML tags if they are proving to be annoying to Google.

Translate with Google.

Replace back the hashes. Voila! Job done! If you're feeling even more daring, instead of replacing the hashes back, replace them with an l18n-suitable structure might prove to be even more worthwhile.

Comment: This was an easy and practical way to do it. I used the RegEx (?<=>)[[:word:] \.\,\:\!\?\_\-\(\)]+?(?=<) to find only text and went ahead with this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to internationalize the code. You need to move all the translatable strings out into a separate file, so that you can shove that through Google and then easily drop in the results.

Researching the topic of PHP I18N will prove rewarding.

Answer (score 0):

Google Translator toolkit is for documents - not so much for source code. You can organize your program's strings as documents and translate them in Google Translator toolkit, and there are, in fact, software projects that do it, but it's contrived. It would be much better to use a different method, as the other people here say.

Put the translatable strings in separate files - you can use something like YAML or JSON, for example, or to just organize your strings as PHP arrays (that's how it's done in MediaWiki, for example). Each message should have a key. Use one file per language or one file with all the languages, and the strings grouped by languages. (By the way, use ISO 639-3 language codes - don't make up your own. Then you'll be able to reuse them in HTML lang attributes.)

After you organized your strings like that, write functions that load the strings from these files by message key and language code, and use these functions to display the messages - never use hardcoded strings.

Finally, put your files up for translation using software such as Pootle, Transifex, Zanata, or the MediaWiki Translate extension.

(Disclaimer: I am a developer of the MediaWiki Translate extension.)

Answer (score 0):

Using something like [Gettext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) (namely [php-gettext](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/)) is IMHO best approach to do that. Another widely used option is to simply extract strings to separate files (be it PHP or JSON) and translate these. However I'd recommend to use Gettext as you will be using standard format with wide range of available tools.